# Pickle dump object raising "Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded" error

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to index one of my drives using a `Linked List`. Each node containing variables of the *path* and a `list` of all **Folders and Directories** in that particular *path*. However, I looked into the error and it doesn't show any error until it reaches the size of **164(*Read Note Below*)**. Greater than that, it raises the formerly mentioned error. The linked list contains approximately 5500 nodes.

**Note:** I tried to use **`sys.setrecursionlimit(x)`** at the beginning of the program and it can go upto 757 nodes for the object being successfully able to dump and load through **`pickle`** by setting **`sys.setrecursionlimit(4558)`**. Increasing this limit, there's no change in the threshold of the total number of nodes in the **`linklist`** object which could be successfully dumped in the file without getting the title error.

**Additional Note:** I replaced the **`import`** package from **`pickle`** to **`cPickle`** and **`sys.setrecursionlimit(13438)`** the threshold number of nodes that could be stored as an object into the file increased drastically to **4470**. I have changed my code accordingly.

Here is my code which is further simplified for the users to make it readable and basically stick to the point. I have omitted many significant functions and parts of the code which in my knowledge has no relevance to the error at all.

```
import cPickle as pickle #originally pickle
import os
import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(13438)
class Link(object):

    def __init__(self, path, dir, file):
        self.path = path
        self.dir = dir
        self.file = file
        self.next = None
    def setNext(self, next):
        self.next = next
    def getPath(self):
        return self.path
    def getData(self):
        print "Node Visited."
    def containsDir(self, dir):
        pass

class LinkList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0
    def insert(self, path, dir, file):
        val = Link(path, dir, file)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = val
            self.tail = val
        else:
            val.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = val
        self.size = self.size + 1
    def insert_bottom(self, path, dir, file):
        new_val = Link(path, dir, file)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_val;
            self.tail = self.head;
        else:
            self.tail.setNext(new_val);
            self.tail = new_val;
        self.size = self.size + 1
    def view(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp != None:
            print temp.getData()
            temp = temp.next

linklist = LinkList()

for (path,dir,files) in os.walk("E:\\"):
    if(dir!=[] or files!=[]):
        linklist.insert_bottom(path, dir, files)
    if(linklist.size>=4477): #This is the threshold of storing this object using cPickle!
        break
print linklist.size
#linklist.view()

output = open("list", "wb")
pickle.dump(linklist, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) #-1 = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL
output.close()
input = open("list", "rb")
obj = pickle.load(input)
```

**And here is the Stack Trace as requested:**

**1:** This is when I store the `linkedlist` of size>164(This repeats for a very large number of times so I am posting the first and last portions of the repeated Stack trace):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "temp.py", line 63 in <module>
pickle.dump(linklist, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) #-1 = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1376, in dump
Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
self.save(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
save(state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
save(v)
...
...
...
...
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
save(state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
save(k)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 271, in save
pid = self.persistent_id(obj)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

**2:(SOLVED)** This is the Stack Trace when I store object of the `linkedlist` limiting it's size to 164 or less. *The output.close() was missing before loading the file.*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "temp.py", line 65, in <module>
obj1 = pickle.load(input)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 995, in load_short_binstring
len = ord(self.read(1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

Comment: just a hunch, but try looking at the part of the code you havent posted here, and see if you've used the name of a function inside the function in a manner that you didnt intend to be recursive. ( or in other words, see if you've accidentally used the name of a function inside that function)

Comment: That isn't possible. I have analysed the above code which precisely shows the error that I'm getting. You can try it. The functions are just string searching algorithms which aren't recursive at all. @KaustavDatta

Comment: @quasoft I tried to narrowed it down to the size(164) of the list where the title error doesn't appear. But after that while loading the file, it raises EOF error.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: `pickle` just doesn't support this depth of nesting. It's kind of bizarre how unfriendly Python is to any sort of linked data structure. There's no built-in linked list or binary search tree, either.

Comment: Added Stack Traces! @1.618

Comment: @user2357112 Maybe you are right. But what about the second Stack Trace while reading the object which is stored according to Python's depth limit of that data structure.

Comment: What's causing the recursion depth to be exceeded is because the data structure is recursive (e.g. the tail node points back to the head node).

Comment: Edit: I just found that that user2357112 is an expert in Python, I happened to go over their answers to the "pickle" tag any my **stack trace 2** is solved. I forgot to close the output file.

Comment: @martineau: pickle handles recursive data structures. Try `l = []; l.append(l); dumped = pickle.dumps(l); loaded = pickle.loads(dumped)`, and you'll find everything works out fine.

Comment: @martineau The tail is also meaning less in this list. But it is accurately handled. And the unposted functions are perfectly working on the linked list. You can check it yourself.

Comment: @user2357112 I just discovered an odd behaviour, while loading the object from the file(limited to 164 size), I printed the `path` variable of the `tail` and surprisingly, it came out as **E:\C Programs\Linked List\Linked List\bin\Debug.** I am wondering it might be related to this.

Comment: @user2357112: I know the documentation says `pickle` handles recursive data structures up to a limit by keeping track of what it has already saved. It appears the OP is exceeding that limit even after doing the `sys.setrecursionlimit(6000)` call.

Comment: @Mr. Robot: It doesn't matter whether your code makes use of the tail node or not — it's in the data structure which means `pickle` has to deal with it.

Comment: @martineau The number of nodes are 5143. I counted that by using the size variable of the `linkedlist`

Comment: @Mr.Robot: That doesn't matter because for some reason it keeps going though them over and over until the recursion limit is reached. The memorization it uses to prevent this appears broken for unknown reasons.

Comment: @martineau: The tail pointing back to the head wouldn't be a problem (and I don't see that happening here, anyway). This isn't a problem with reference loops, just nesting depth. Something like `l = []; for i in xrange(10000): l = [l]` breaks `pickle` the same way.

Comment: @martineau The memory isn't broken. Have you tried running it? Let me add a `view` function just to iterate over all the nodes without getting stuck.

Comment: @user2357112: In `insert_bottom()` it does a `self.tail = self.head`. From the simple example in the code in your comment, it seems this is a limitation due to how `pickle` is implemented.

Comment: I get an EOF trying to load right after dumping

Comment: @Mr. Robot: Yes, I have been running it (but I only have about 2500 entries). I'll try it on something bigger.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: That's because `output` was left open.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Try running the updated code now. It will run.

Comment: best I can get to is  3300 with `sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You mean with my program or just a simple linked list?

Comment: @Mr.Robot, with your program `sys.setrecursionlimit(30000)` I can get to `6000`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 6000, what? The no. linked list nodes created, no. of depth nodes upto which `pickle` stores it easily or is it something else?

Comment: yes, as in  `if linklist.size > 6000; break`

Comment: My program crashes into "Python.exe has stopped working" if I do this. I use version 2.7.11.

Comment: It is platform dependant, I actually get a sigenv at  4300 not 6k

Comment: @martineau: Those attributes only stay set like that for a 1-element list, and the problem case is bigger than one element.

Comment: Sorry, my internet went down yesterday. So @PadraicCunningham what is a sigenv?

Comment: My program can go upto 757 nodes for the object being successfully able to `dump` and `load` through `pickle` by setting `sys.setrecursionlimit(4558)`. Above this limit, there's no change in the threshold of the total number of nodes in the object which are able to be successfully dumped in the file without getting the title error.

Comment: @Mr.Robot, basically the same as what is happening in windows on linux

Comment: I changed from `pickle` to `cPickle` and the threshold number of nodes jumped to **4470** nodes! That's quite an improvement.

Comment: Is it possible there's loop in the file system where some subpath points back to a higher level in the file hierarchy — via a symbolic link or junction — essentially making the whole thing appear to be infinite. When I tried your code on something like that I have, I got the same results. The logic in `pickle` that detects identical objects to handle recursive data structures doesn't work for a case like that because the `Links`s for iterative visits of the same object will have different data store in it (i.e. a longer and longer `path`).